If I connect a Typeform to Slack can I tag a particular person when the typeform is submitted?
I have a typeform passing data to slack for an internal process. The process goes like this:

a member of Team 1 fills out the form
Form is submitted to a slack channel
Team 2 responds to the data in the form with a recommendation based on the input in the form.

Team 1 has about 15 members.
Team 2 has 2 members making recommendations.
What I'd like is to be able to tag the person from Team 1 that submits the form in Slack so they are notified when the person from Team 2 responds to their submission.
Can this be done?

This sounds like something you could implement using Typeform webhooks + Slack API.
Or build using a nocode workflow solution like Zapier or Make.
There is a specific syntax for writing a message in Slack, which is described in their documentation.
Hi <@U012AB3CD>
Where U012AB3CD is the user's id.
One challenge could be mapping people's name with their id on Slack.
